Do I need an input capacitor for a switching voltage regulator, if I already have electrolytic capacitors?
Assume that you're converting 24VAC to 24VDC (which becomes about 32 in reality).

Then you want to covert the 24VDC to 7.5V by using a switching voltage regulator.
You're already using 220 uF caps in parallell. So that leads to the question:
Question:
Do I need a 10 uF input capacitor for the switching voltage regulator, or will the 220 electrolytic caps stablize the voltage for the switching regulator as well?


Yes. You need the 10uF input capacitor.
There is no way even the three (random) electrolytics can handle the job of the input cap, you likely cannot even place the nearest electrolytic as close to the chip input as required.
The data sheet says the input cap needs to be high frequency decoupling capacitor (rules out electrolytics basically already). They recommend high quality ceramic caps (basic electrolytics are not ceramic nor high quality).
Basically, the ESR of a single special low ESR electrolytic ceramic cap can still be between 10x to 100x higher than any bog-standard X7R ceramic cap.

Thank you for the answer.

Datasheet for ti.com LMR54406 page 21 - 8.2.2.5 Input Capacitor Selection describes the input capacitor requirement. I'd summarize the requirements in this order of importance:

Ceramic (MLCC)
Low ESR, around 10mOhm (0.01 ohm)
X5R or X7R temperature characteristic (not Y5V, not NP0)
voltage rating 2x the working voltage (i.e. 50V or greater)
capacitance 2.2uF or greater
size appropriate for your board

This is one of the places where you can't just use any random part, use a reliable vendor that provides capacitor datasheets. (Off the top of my head, in no particular order, I'd look at: Murata, TDK, AVX, Nichicon, Vishay) If you don't see "Low ESR" as one of the bullet points on the front page of the datasheet, it's not the right capacitor for this job.
Be sure to also check out datasheet page 19 - 8.2.2.3 Inductor Selection. The switch mode power supply requires the kind of inductor that can store a lot of energy, not just a ferrite bead or an RF choke. Again, be sure to get a datasheet, and verify the LI2 (energy storage per cycle) and saturation current (which limits the peak current). (My favorite vendors for this are Sumida, TDK, Coilcraft.)
PCB layout is also extremely important for switch mode converters.
Datasheet page 26 - figure 8.11 Layout shows the recommended PCB layout. I've worked with switch mode power supplies for decades; it's important to follow the vendor's recommended layout. Specifically:

compact, tight loop for VIN-GND input capacitor
compact, tight loop for SW-VOUT-GND output inductor and output capacitor
VOUT, VIN, GND, SW copper on layer 1
don't just route traces, place large copper fill areas over them, as large as practical
FB feedback resistors close to the FB pin to minimize the exposure of the high-impedance input
far end of FB sense divider goes through via to other side of board, connects through a via at the exact point where VOUT should be regulated


Ceramic caps would not specify "low ESR" on their data sheet. That's mainly electrolytic terminology. A generic 10uF 10VDC X7R cap in 0805 (2012M) package has less than 10mOhms ESR even without being especially low ESR.

Why not C0G/NP0?

Yes you need a quality capacitor.  Bulk decoupling will not likely work due to a the voltage drop across the capacitor's ESR, and even if it does it will almost certainly radiate badly failing any EMC radiated emissions tests.
The input capacitor of the buck converter needs to be low ESR and placed as close as possible to the buck controller IC as it acts as the return for AC currents.  This minimizes EMI as well as supports proper operation.
If you want to ensure good EMI performance you'll also want to place your switch (be it a diode or a transistor) close to the IC too to minimize the loop area formed by these.
This is the so called "hot loop" for a buck topology.  You can read in about it here at the link below, but the basic idea is that you want to keep the lop where currents are discontinuous as small as possible.  In a buck converter you get the 2 states in which different currents will flow.  If you look at the diagram you will notice that some currents go from current flowing to none and in some other instances, the current flips direction.  I've marked them in red. This is the high di/dt currents where you need to minimize the loop area.

https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/what-actually-is-a-hot-loop.html
The other consideration is the node between the switches and the inductor.  This node has an uncontrolled voltage when switching.  This can create opportunities for E-field radiation/coupling, so it is best to keep this node as small as possible on your design.  Additionally, the design should have a solid ground return plane underneath it which helps keep the loop areas small and therefore reduce E and H fields.
